# Как обновлять содержимое листбокса?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

застрял в казалось бы, очевидном месте. Есть программа, она предлагает выбрать папку, в которой желательно лежат картинки в выбранном пользователем расширении(выбор расширения происходит через радиокнопки). Затем все объекты из выбранной папки в выбранном расширении попадают в листбокс и при нажатии на них в окошке листбокса они выводятся на пикчербокс. Вот вопрос. Что нужно сделать, чтобы после открытия каталога с картинками, при переключении радиокнопок содержимое листбокса обновлялось в соответствии с условиями на радиокнопках?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace FollowMeLookAtMe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string folderName;
        private string fileType;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            radioButton1.Checked = true;
        }
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                folderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            else
                return;
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(fileType);
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(Files);
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName";
        }
        private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                FileInfo fi = (FileInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem;
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = fi.FullName;
            }
        }
        private void RadioButtons_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                fileType = "*.jpg";
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                fileType = "*.png";
            }

            else
            {
                fileType = "*.bmp";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void RadioButtons_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {

                fileType = "*.jpg";
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                fileType = "*.png";
            }

            else
            {
                fileType = "*.bmp";
            }
            if (folderName != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
                FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(fileType);
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(Files);
                listBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName";
            }

        }
```

Немного дополнил последний метод программы. Очень удобно получилось, пусть и повторилось. Надеюсь, кто-то найдёт этот ответ полезным.